# Emberjs and Simple Auth for any $.ajax

Tags: ember.js, ember-simple-auth

I am doing an $.ajax post command and i currently have an authenticated session on the client side. I am trying to figure out how to add the token to the ajax call (as on the server i check the token to see if it matches in my local database. How is it possible to use that same auth token in a generic ajax call ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You add the token as a request header in your authorizer.

To do this, either use one of the [including solutions](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth#authorizers) (if you're using the corresponding backend), or [implement your own custom authorizer](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth#implementing-a-custom-authorizer).

If you have to write your own, you can look at the [devise authorizer's `authorize` method](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/blob/master/packages/ember-simple-auth-devise/lib/simple-auth-devise/authorizers/devise.js#L68-L75) for an example of how to add the header.